# CSharpCodeProvider: Why is a result of compilation out of context when debugging

Tags: c#, codedom

I have following code snippet that i use to compile class at the run time.

```
//now compile the runner
var codeProvider = new CSharpCodeProvider(
  new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "CompilerVersion", "v3.5" } });

string[] references = new string[]
  {
    "System.dll", "System.Core.dll", "System.Core.dll"
  };
CompilerParameters parameters = new CompilerParameters();

parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.AddRange(references);               
parameters.OutputAssembly = "CGRunner";
parameters.GenerateInMemory = true;
parameters.TreatWarningsAsErrors = true;

CompilerResults result = codeProvider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, template);
```

Whenever I step through the code to debug the unit test, and I try to see what is the value of "result" I get an error that name "result"  does not exist in current context. Why?

Comment: Are you debugging in release mode? This may happen to optimizations of unused variable.

Comment: No, I am not, it is in debug mode. Reason I am debugging is because next line is supposed to load assembly and use Activator.CreateInstance, but it cannot find it so it throws an error.

Comment: You wanna post your question as an answer, slightly modified. I had "Optimize Code" checked in project build properties. Your "optimizations of unused variable"  gave an idea to check that.

Comment: @Elisha - this comment only exists (with the @prefix) to draw your attention to @epitka's comment ("post that as an answer").

Comment: for info, if you want to make sure another user sees your reply to their comment, use the @prefix - then it shows in their messages area (only works for the first @whatever in your comment, though)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you debugging in release mode? This may happen to optimizations of unused variable.

For example:

```
public void OptimizedMethod()
{
    int x = 5; // In optimized mode it's not possible to watch the variable
}
```

Code optimization happens when running in release mode, or when setting "Optimize code" in project properties (under build tab)